# How to calculate the pH of a propanoate buffer after addition of sodium hydroxide?

Tags: homework, acid-base, solutions

I've calculated the pH of the buffer solution, as seen. 
The question I'm referring to is part d), which asks: 'Calculate the pH of the solution after 0.01 mols of NaOH are added to  500$cm^3$ of the solution'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of the NaOH will "use up" 0.01 mol of propanoic acid and "create" 0.01 mol of propionate. To make things easier, just work in molarity. Thus 0.02 M NaOH.

The pH of the final solution can be found by adjusting the equation you used in part b,

$pH = -log \left( 1.26 \times 10^{-5}\frac{0.1-0.02}{0.05+0.02} \right)=4.84$

The result agrees with our expectations. Since the solution is a buffer, the pH is not expected to drastically change with the addition of a strong base. It is buffered.